# .htaccess - Disabling caching only in one directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I would like to keep my .htaccess caching my whole public_html folder, except for one folder, called SmartBackup.
Could someone tell me a way to do it?

Here's my folder structure:
[image]

Here's my current htaccess code, that is on 'public_html' folder:

```
# Enable expiration control
ExpiresActive On

# Default expiration: 1 hour after request
ExpiresDefault "now plus 1 week"

# CSS and JS expiration: 1 week after request
ExpiresByType text/css "now plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "now plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "now plus 1 week"

# Image files expiration: 1 month after request
ExpiresByType image/bmp "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jp2 "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/pipeg "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/tiff "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/ico "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/icon "now plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon A2592000
ExpiresByType text/ico "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/ico "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/vnd.wap.wbmp "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/vnd.wap.wbxml "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/smil "now plus 1 month"

# Audio files expiration: 1 month after request
ExpiresByType audio/basic "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType audio/mid "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType audio/midi "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType audio/mpeg "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType audio/x-aiff "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType audio/x-mpegurl "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType audio/x-pn-realaudio "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType audio/x-wav "now plus 1 month"

# Movie files expiration: 1 month after request
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType x-world/x-vrml "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/x-msvideo "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/mpeg "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/mp4 "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/quicktime "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/x-la-asf "now plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType video/x-ms-asf "now plus 1 month"
```

Comment: Why is SmartBackup under public_html in the first place? :-|

Comment: It's a backup script.

Comment: Yes, I figured... But why is it not configured to write backups over to `public_html/../SmartBackup`? This would spare you the need to mess around with caching, no?

Comment: I guess it wouldn't, because the htaccess is acting in all folders, subfolders and files of public_html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could overwrite the configuration with `ExpiresActive Off` for the subdirectory.

a) Place an additional `.htaccess` file in the mentioned directory

b) Wrap it in a `<directory /not-expiring-directory/>` tag

Comment: So the htaccess file on the subdirectory would overwrite the htaccess that is one directory up?

Comment: I've used ExpiresActive Off in the subdirectory and I guess it's working, thanks :)